# Windows 7 media center boot without password

Tags: windows-7, passwords, windows-media-center

I always access my Media center computer through remote desktop connection, thus the media center requires a password. Everytime I reboot the media center, it needs to enter a password to login. Is there a way to keep the password on the media center (The media center needs to be password protected to be accessible via remote desktop connection), but to login automatically?

Is there a way to fix this? or should I better use ubuntu to have a media center?

Answer (score 1):

You can facilitate the user automaticly logging in by following the steps referred to [in the top answer of this question](https://superuser.com/questions/21617/turn-off-automatic-login-with-windows-7).

Though, I recommend you use a service like TightVNC instead, as you will not have to RDP-in with a password where you actively "lock" the session that is displayed on your TV for instance.