# How to lock Windows screen on startup?

Tags: windows-7, security, window, lock-screen

I like to go get coffee while the computer starts. However we have a policy that says the screen must be locked when away.

How can I make sure that the screen locks immediately after logging in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
RUNDLL32 USER32.DLL,LockWorkStation
```

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/rundll.php

You can create a Shortcut to the `c:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe` and add the parameter.
If you put this shortcut in the Autostart folder, your computer will be locked after login.

Screenshot is german, but the shortcut **target** should look like this, (verified with Windows 8 but should work with Windows 2000+)

[image: shortcut]

Comment: +1, I used to use this to lock my XP workstation from RDP sessions.

Comment: -1. [Raymond Chen/The Old New Thing: What can go wrong when you mismatch the calling convention?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx): *"[The function signature required for functions called by rundll32.exe is documented in this Knowledge Base article.] That hasn't stopped people from using rundll32 to call random functions that **weren't designed to be called by rundll32, like [user32 LockWorkStation]** or [user32 ExitWindowsEx]."* Besides, [rundll32 is deprecated since Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/04/10382242.aspx).

Comment: @Michael, didn't know about that, thanks. Raymond has a good point and here are some more reasons why not to use rundll http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/04/10382242.aspx and as a programmer it makes sense to say `Don't use it, call the function yourself` but as a user it should be more like `Use it at your own risk, if it works for you`

Comment: @SchlaWiener I might agree, if it wasn't for the fact that as pointed out by Raymond Chen this kind of trick can work *intermittently*. Working as a programmer, *intermittently occuring bugs* are the ones I loathe the most trying to track down. And I don't want to think about what calling (random) Win32 API functions with *random parameters* could potentially do to application state. If I feel like it later today or this weekend, maybe I'll put together a small application that simply calls LockWorkStation as it was intended to be called, and put it somewhere for everyone's benefit.

Comment: seems to work for me!

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, when you [disable auto login](https://superuser.com/questions/21617/turn-off-automatic-login-with-windows-7) the lock screen will be automatically activated.

Comment: But that will prevent the "preloading" of apps that are run at first login (mail client, browser)

Comment: Right. I have another idea in mind, I will think about it

Comment: Well I thought about launching the executable in system32 which locks the computer, and apparently it's rundll32 - and SchlaWiener gave you great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I copy the following from http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/293057-how-do-i-completely-remove-user-lock-screen-when-i-boot-up.html:

http://s8.postimg.org/ohlejdscz/image.jpg

To lock, choose `Require a password (recommended).` I see that this does NOT state 'Lock' explicitly, but once you choose this, your home screen will become Locked, even without a password.